# How to type a subproperty of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know this sounds like a generic question, but I wasn't quite able to find an answer online.

Suppose I have the following object,

```
const myObject = {
    property: {
        subProperty: null
    },
}
```

The following works just fine:

```
const getValue = (): string => 'property'

const value = myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]
```

However when I try to type the `subProperty` value, I get an error. Here's how I try typing it:

```
const getValue = (): string => 'property'
const getSubValue = (): string => 'subProperty'

const value = myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]

const subValue = myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject][getSubValue() as keyof typeof myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]]
```

I'm aware that I can change the two methods to the following:

```
const getValue = (): 'property' => 'property'
const getSubValue = (): 'subProperty' => 'subProperty'
```

This will work without the `keyof typeof` indicator, but obviously I need to keep the return value of the two functions to be `string`.

Comment: By the time you're using this `getValue() as keyof typeof myObject][getSubValue() as keyof typeof myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]` as a type I'm not sure you're gaining much value. Define an interface for the object, with declared sub types if necessary.

Comment: Why are you declaring the return type of `getValue`? If you omit `string` then typescript should infer the type correctly based on the function body.

Comment: @Olian04 This is a simple, minimal example. I have no way of knowing what string the function would return. In this case, it returns only `"property"` always, but in an AJAX call, it could return any string

Comment: @pilchard I can define an interface for `myObject`, but the key is dynamic. The method's return value is unknown, as far as TS is concerned, because it is fetched in an AJAX call

Comment: @MikeK in that case, doing `myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]` doesn't make any sense at all. You are bypassing the type system rather than using it.

Comment: @Olian04 so how would I solve the problem above?

Comment: @MikeK A lot of time is being wasted because of the lack of clarity on what you are trying to do much less what the actual error you are getting is. Please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post the actual error you are getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the TypeScript parser isn't able to handle the complexity of the expression. So if you use an intermediate variable, it will work:

```
const value = myObject[getValue() as keyof typeof myObject]
const subValue = value[getSubValue() as keyof typeof value]
```